# 3-States on a Submit Button

Tags: html, css, image, forms, button

I was wondering how I could add 3-States to a Submit Button. By states I mean so that the button changes image when hovered over, clicked and just static/untouched. I'd prefer if the solution used purely HTML & CSS but Javascript is fine too. Thank-You!

Comment: When you say clicked, do you mean the color changes during the clicking action (as answered by `:active` case below), or that, once clicked, it changes and stays that color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it easier to give id's or classes to such things to make it easier. You can do something like this in jquery:

Let's say that the button has a #derp id.

```
$("#derp").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("pressed");
});
```

Basically this will add or remove the "pressed" class from the item based on its state. Just add the CSS for .pressed and you're ready to go.

```
#derp {...}
#derp:hover {...}
#derp:active {...}
#derp.pressed {...}
```

Comment: hmm.. Im not sure I completely understand so what does the above jQuery code do? Does it change the buttons class? or?
Sorry I haven't used jQuery.

Comment: I looked into jQuery and it makes more sense now. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. Yeah, so there is no native way to do this without javascript. 

What it does is, if that element doesn't have the "pressed" class, it will add that class when clicked on the element. And if it does, it will simply remove the class. 

It's more of a shorthand property on jquery, this can also be done with addClass and removeClass functions but toggleClass is basicly both of them combined specifically for purposes such as these.

Comment: The reason for the using the toggle is, since you want it to be selected when clicked, its either something like a checkbox behavior, or a tab navigation. Both cases require it to be deactivated at some point, and using toggleClass lets you do that easier.

Comment: I see well does it add the whole class="derp" to the tag or does it just add the value derp to the class attribute. 
Would I need to add the class attribute or is that done automatically as-well. Once again, sorry for my newbiness, and thanks.

Comment: yeah, it adds the whole class tag if it's missing, or just the class if you already have another class since you can have multiple. You don't have to do anything. Here's a small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cQQWY/1/

Comment: Ahk Thanks, that explains everything.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
button[type=submit]
button[type=submit]:hover
button[type=submit]:active
```

EDIT: Keeping the "clicked" state would work something like this with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/WYTHG/1/

Comment: But how would I make the button change when its clicked and stay that way. To show that is pressed? Thanks

Comment: Then you would have to resort to adding a class on click via javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/jfeltis/Ufs7u/

Comment: Thanks, Im just not sure how to make the button stay the that way when pressed? Thank-You.

Comment: You would need to use javascript (jQuery would be the simplest solution) to get your desired effect.  See @markvandencorput's jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The normal state should be clear for you, the other two can styles with .element:hover and .element:active

Comment: When clicked it should stay as the new image yes.

Comment: The :active status is only shown, as long as the button is clicked itself. If you want to change the image after click, you need to implement a javascript solution.